# Which html property to use for selecting nodes when testing React components with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm unit testing react components using Enzyme and I'm trying to figure out what html property to use to decorate nodes with enough information for me to select them in my tests. I'm hesitant to use className for a couple reasons. First if I set a className it implies that there is some styling specific to that node, and in many cases in my tests I just need a way to select the node and assert some things about it. Second I'm using CSS Modules so setting *global* class names just to support the unit tests feels wrong. Is there a good alternative to the `class` property people use for adding arbitrary info to nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You're testing them via DOM rendering or shallow rendering? If shallow rendering you can set an arbitrary prop and assert on that. If you want to add arbitrary properties to DOM nodes you can use `data-` properties if there's not a better way to select the nodes you need to assert on.

Comment: I'm shallow rendering so arbitrary prop is fair game. I guess I was wondering if there's a decently semantic convention for the prop to select on. `<Link testingHook="foo" />` feels kinda gross. Maybe something like "purpose" would be good, but I'm curios what other people are doing.

Comment: Maybe someone else can make a more general suggestion, but I don't know what else to suggest without knowing more about what data is available in your testing scenario.